# Load data of infinite grid dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I have created an infinite grid using Extjs 6.7. In which, records are getting loaded from the store proxy. How can it be done dynamically using Ajax calls?

Also, have to display the count of loaded records and total records.
Something like `5 of 100`.

I have tried `store.count()` but it's returning total count so how to fetch loaded records.

`store.getData().getCount()` returns the count but it doesnt changes after 8-9 iterations, seems data is getting overridden in buffered store.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.BufferedStore', {

            fields: [
                'firstName', 'lastName',
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'int'
                }],

            leadingBufferZone: 5,
            pageSize: 1,
            remoteSort: true,
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'https://llbzr8dkzl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/user',
                reader: {
                    rootProperty: 'users',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            id: 'myGrid',               
            title: 'Infinite Grid',
            width: 650,
            height: 500,
            store: store,
            scrollable: true,
            features: {
                ftype: 'grouping'
            },
            plugins: {
                gridfilters: true
            },

            columns: {
                defaults: {
                    filter: {
                        type: 'string'
                    }
                },
                items: [{
                    text: 'First Name',
                    width: 150,
                    dataIndex: 'firstName'
                }, {
                    text: 'Last Name',
                    width: 150,
                    dataIndex: 'lastName'
                }, {
                    text: 'Id',
                    width: 50,
                    dataIndex: 'id',
                    filter: {
                        type: 'number'
                    }
                } ]
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any hints or examples please. The fiddle is available [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33nb).

Comment: Do you mean ajax proxy? or  exactly ajax?

Comment: Ajax calls using rest API

Comment: Okay, I'm confused. You want a buffered store with the ability to show summary data. Reality is buffered store is used to replace a paging store. You would have to custom code any record information to display. This also depends on leading and trailing buffer zones in determine the number of records actually available as buffered store removes data outside of your buffer zone settings. Why not use a store and page your results with the sent start and end points? It would be the quickest way to show total records, what page and what record your on based on page size.

Comment: that seems the good suggestion but i am worried if large data will make my grid slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of records something like this:

```
store.getData().length
```

but the problem is that previously downloaded data is deleted (~ 250 items in my example)

Don't understand why `getCount` return total count

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33o0)

Comment: Ow, in BufferedStore `getCount` is overwrited and private https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/src/BufferedStore.js.html#Ext.data.BufferedStore-method-getCount

Comment: if you want to get not the maximum number of elements in your store but the last  border use `store.lastRequestEnd`

Comment: How to populate grid with ajax call, any example

Comment: You mean side ajax call? At what event should this be done, and why?

Comment: i have couple of filters to do on response so looking for ajax calls to implement infinite grid

Comment: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.data.BufferedStore.html#cfg-remoteFilter
remoteFilter didn't suitable for solving this problem? changed my fiddle for work with remoteFilter

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i am actually looking for populating grid with ajax request without using any store proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following fiddle which is actually using store's ajax proxy to implement infinite scrolling.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3402

**Edit**:
If you want to use Ext.Ajax.request method because of some reasons, you can check below fiddle, its using Ajax.request method to get more items - 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/341a